# Check if array empty

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

**Problem:** unwanted empty POST(s) is saved when saving multiple POSTs.

**Question:** how do I check if an array is empty?

I want to check if the `$value[0]` is empty and only save the values containing text.

Please feel free to change the code below or use a new example.

```
foreach ($_POST['bedomning'] as $elevens_id => $value) {

    $ident = $_POST['ident'];   
    $amne_id = $_POST['amne_id'];   
    $datumet = $_POST['datum'];         
    $lararen = $_SESSION['lid'];

    $array_empty = array_filter($value[0]);

    if (!empty($array_empty)){   

        try{    

            $ny_bedomning  = $db->prepare("             
                INSERT INTO `abb_larare` 
                (ident, amne_id, abb_bed_text, elev_id, lid, datum) 
                VALUES (:ident, :amne_id, :abb_bed_text, :elev_id, :lid, :datum) 
            ");                         

            $ny_bedomning->bindParam(':ident', $ident, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ny_bedomning->bindParam(':amne_id', $amne_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $ny_bedomning->bindParam(':abb_bed_text', $value[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ny_bedomning->bindParam(':elev_id', $elevens_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
            $ny_bedomning->bindParam(':lid', $lararen, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $ny_bedomning->bindParam(':datum', $datumet, PDO::PARAM_STR);       

            $ny_bedomning->execute();   

        }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `empty()` to check empty value. Try with -

```
if (!empty($value[0])) {
   // do staff
}
```

`empty` works for -

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)